# jQuery show/hide using select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to apply a show/hide jQuery function to a html drop down box. I want to be able to hide one option and show another when an option from the drop down is selected. This jQuery works with a normal button but not the drop down.

```
<select style="margin-left:30px;">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please select a region</option>
    <option id="uk_btn" value="1">UK</option>
    <option id="usa_btn" value="2">USA</option>
</select>

<script>
    $("#usa_btn").click(function(){
      $("#usa_tbl").show();
      $("#uk_tbl").hide();
    });
</script>
<script>
    $("#uk_btn").click(function(){
      $("#uk_tbl").show();
      $("#usa_tbl").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have no id on select then you can try

```
$('select').change(function(){
     var val = $(this ).val();
     if(val == 2) {
          $("#usa_tbl").show();
          $("#uk_tbl").hide();
     } else {
          $("#uk_tbl").show();
          $("#usa_tbl").hide();
     }
});
```

or you can do by id

```
<select id="select_id" style="margin-left:30px;">
```

now

```
$('#select_id').change(function(){
....same as previous
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra comments on each snippet to!

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the **event for the select box** like

```
$('select').change(function(){
     var val = $(this + 'option:selected').attr('id');
     if(val == 'uk_btn') {
          $("#usa_tbl").hide();
          $("#uk_tbl").show();
     } elseif(val == 'usa_btn') {
          $("#uk_tbl").hide();
          $("#usa_tbl").show();
     }
});
```

You can also check using `value` of the check box like

```
var val = $(this).val();
if(val == '1') {
     $("#usa_tbl").hide();
     $("#uk_tbl").show();
} elseif (val == '2') {
     $("#uk_tbl").hide();
     $("#usa_tbl").show();
}
```

Comment: Your solution with if(val == 'uk_btn') code can be wrong if the first option "Please select a region" is selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
// Cache the elements first
var $usa_tbl = $("#usa_tbl");
var $uk_tbl = $("#uk_tbl");

// Add a change event handler for the select element
$("#select_ID").change(function () {
    if (this.value === '2') {
        $usa_tbl.show();
        $uk_tbl.hide();
    } else if (this.value === '1') {
        $uk_tbl.show();
        $usa_tbl.hide();
    } else {
        $uk_tbl.hide();
        $usa_tbl.hide();
    }
});
```

where, `select_ID` is the ID of the select element.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y77cu/)

Answer (score 1):

*Root cause:* There is no ***id*** matching for `select` in your js.

```
<select style="margin-left:30px;">  //id attribute is missing
```

instead use **`change`** event handler

```
 <select style="margin-left:30px;" id="usa_btn">
```

**JS:**

```
 $("#usa_btn").change(function(){
      alert($(this).val());  // to get the value of selected option based on it 
                             // add your condition
      $("#usa_tbl").show();
      $("#uk_tbl").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="country" style="margin-left:30px;">
```

then

```
$("#country").change(function(){
   $('[id$="_tbl"]').hide();
   $('#' + this.value.replace('_btn', '_tbl')) .show()
});
```